# Prolog predicate different solution cases

Tags: prolog

I have 2 simple rules, which defines if 2 variables are in relation ship
grandfather: `grandfather(X,Y):-male(X), parent(X,Z), parent(Z,Y).`

father: `svekr(X,Y):-male(X), female(Y),parent(X,Z),(marriage(Z,Y);marriage(Y,Z)).`

for grandfather, when I'm trying to get all possible results using `;` , program gives me answer `yes`. 
This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, program understands that there is no more possible solutions, so the program gives final answer is `X = pat` and `Y = tony` without confirmation.

But for father in law it goes like this:

[image]

This time, program does ask, if there is a need to find another solution it will fail and answer is no. 
So my quesstion is, why in one case it gives YES with no confirmation and in other case it gives NO with confirmation?

Full code in here https://pastebin.com/9HpEnuAz

Comment: Sloppy! Include your code in the question (no link to pastebin) and OCR that text data (no link to imgur).

Comment: This is just an extra choice point and it's nothing to worry about. In `svekr/2`, Prolog probably succeeded in `marriage(Z,Y)`, gave you `X = pat, Y = samantha` and then you pressed `;` to get another answer, Prolog backed up and tried `marriage(Y,Z)` and found no solutions that way. In `grandfather/2` it had already exhausted all the facts when it gave you `X = pat, Y = tony` and knew it had no more things to try. This won't cause any real problems and fixing it probably isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
a(1).
a(2).
```

resulting in

```
?- a(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2.

true.
```

Prolog knows that there is no rule after `a(2)`, so it can give a definite answer.

Now, on the other hand:

```
a(1).
a(2).
a(3) :-  0 > 1.
```

Here, after `a(2)`, we see another rule, giving another *choice point*. This is like a closed door - you can choose to try to open it, but you don't know whether anything is behind at or whether it will open at all. However, Prolog sees the door and asks you if it should try:

```
a(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
false.
```

Since this particular door is locked (0 is not greater than 1), it responds with `false`, meaning "I failed to find another answer".

You can usually just ignore extra choice points although there can be performance implications sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks for clarifying it!